# Regarding Game Time in Libgdx

Tags: android, libgdx, game-engine

I have actor Rectangle and powerUp Rectangle and I want that when It collides with actor will have power for 10 seconds. This was achieved as follows :

```
if (powerBoxRect.overlaps(actorRectObj)) {
    powerUpTime = System.currentTimeMillis() + 10000;
}

if (powerUpTime > System.currentTimeMillis()) {
        powerActor = IMMUNEACTOR;
    }
```

But as I have taken any power and press pause button my game is go to paused state and after 10 seconds when I resume my game,power is lost because meanwhile system time is running.
I want to know that how can I stop system time or libgdx provides any other feature to handle this situation?

Comment: with libgdx 0.9.9 they provided time api

Answer (score 1):

```
float time = 0;
int maxTime = 3;


public void update() {

time += Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime();

 if(time > maxTime) {

// DO YOUR THING
 }


}
```